# Remove duplicates keeping the last occurrence

Tags: regex

Given this haystack and `Regex PCRE2(PHP>=7.3)`:

```
#1       #2      #3
green          [foo] [foo1]
red             [foo]
blue                  [foo] [foo1] [foo2]
yellow             [foo2]
green          [foo]
green          [foo] [foo1]
red             [foo]
pink                  [foo3]
```

Where:

`#1` is always a string that can contain numbers but no spaces.

`#2` is always a random amount of space between `#1` and `3`.

`#3` same as `#1` but inside of brackets `[ ]` and can exist multiple brackets.

I'm trying to remove all lines containing dupes on `#1` but keeping the last dupe line found.

It would look like:

```
blue                  [foo] [foo1] [foo2]
yellow             [foo2]
green          [foo] [foo1]
red             [foo]
pink                  [foo3]
```

Cleared all lines that contain the same string on `#1` keeping only the last.

And the lines that don't contain dupes on `#1` as for example:

`pink     [foo3]` keep them.

I tried to explain it in the most detail possible, let me know if it is still unclear or if it's not possible with regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert matches of the following regular expression (with flags `g`, `m` and `i`) to empty strings:

```
^([a-z\d]).*\n(?![\s\S]*\b^\1\b)
```

The flag `g` prevents returning after the first match, `m` (*multiline*) causes `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of lines rather than the beginning and end of the string, and `i` makes matches case insensitive.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R786cX/1)

The elements of the expression are as follows:

```
^             # match beginning of line
([a-z\d])     # match one or more letters or digits and save to capture group 1
.*            # match zero or more characters other than newlines
\n            # match linefeed
(?!           # begin negative lookahead
  [\s\S]*     # match zero or more characters including line terminators
  \b^\1\b     # match content of group 1 with word breaks before and after
)             # end negative lookahead
```

Note that `.` matches carriage returns `\r`. If the last line may not end with a line feed change `\n` to `(?:\n|$)`.

---

If you wish to identify any strings that do not possess the required format you can use the following regular expression to match incorrectly-formatted lines:

```
^(?![a-z\d]*(?: *\[[^[\]\r\n]*\])+\r?\n).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/25Xbwl/1)

Hover your cursor over each element of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of the function of that element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^(\S+)\h+\[\S*\](?!\S).*$(?![\s\S]*^\1)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**
- `\h+` Match 1+ spaces
- `\[\S*\](?!\S)` Match from an opening `[` till closing `]` and assert a whitespace boundary to the right to not match `[foo]a`
- `.*$` Match the rest of the line
- `(?![\s\S]*^\1)` Negative lookahead, assert that capture group 1 does not occur anymore in the text

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nL70cW/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/K9Xln).

For example

```
$re = '/^(\S+)\h+\[\S*\](?!\S).*$(?![\s\S]*^\1)/m';
$str = 'green          [foo] [foo1]
red             [foo]
blue                  [foo] [foo1] [foo2]
yellow             [foo2]
green          [foo]
green          [foo] [foo1]
red             [foo]
pink                  [foo3]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue                  [foo] [foo1] [foo2]
    [1] => yellow             [foo2]
    [2] => green          [foo] [foo1]
    [3] => red             [foo]
    [4] => pink                  [foo3]
)
```